# Activated but still "The requested Payment Method is not available." as registered user only

Tags: configuration, checkout, payment, ce-1.7.0.2

I activated several Payment Method and those are getting displayed on the checkout page.
But regardless which option I select Magento always returns:

> The requested Payment Method is not available.

The problem only occurs if I use a registered user. Guest works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following (ordered by the effort it would take, if one step does not help you, take the next one)

1. Check the allowed countries that you can configure for each payment method in the admin backend.
2. Check the error logs (`system.log`, `exception.log` after enabling them)
3. Debug into the `\Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isAvailable()` method to see what is going on.

Comment: 1. payment is allowed for each country 2. Log is empty 3. $isActive is false with `getConfigData()`

Comment: What is subtotal of your cart?

Comment: @Sergy Subtotal is €22.80

Comment: Did you use any cart rules, reward bonuses that can reduce totals amount ot 0.00?

Comment: @Sergy I have no cart or product rules

Comment: @PiTheNumber: do you mean `$isActive = (bool)(int)$this->getConfigData('active', $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null);
` returns false? Is the payment method active for all stores? There might be something going wrong with the current store or the store of the quote.

Comment: Hm, if you have magerun installed, what's the output of `n98-magerun.phar config:get "payment/*/active"`

Comment: Could you elaborate how to do Step 3? Sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are two places, where this exception is thrown:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php:83
```

and

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php:151
```

I would say the exception comes from the second part. If I understand it correctly, the first part is a real error, the second is a failed test.

as @Alex said, check `\Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isAvailable()`, there is another "problem" which may be happen: Recurring profiles. Do you try to buy a subscription? Then maybe the method can not be used for this.

Do you have xdebug? It is a great tool for such problems, just hook into the `isAvailable()` methods and check where the return value is set to false.

Comment: It is set to false at the start of isAvailable(): `$isActive = (bool)(int)$this->getConfigData('active', $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null);`

Comment: then go to the backend, `System > Config > Payment Methods` and change the dropdown in the upper left wether you are on store view level. Then check the configuration. Maybe you changed it on default level, but it is somewhere overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3 I am also getting same error.
I was missing to configure methodCode in di.xml.

I added method code like below in di.xml and my issue resolved.

```
<type name="Magento\Braintree\Gateway\Config\Config">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="methodCode" xsi:type="const">Magento\Braintree\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</argument>
        </arguments>
 </type>
```