# The requested Payment Method is not available in magento order grid backend

Tags: order-grid, magento1.9.2.3, paypal-payments-pro

I recently changed Website Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout) (Email Associated with PayPal Merchant Account,API Username,API Password,API Signature) in magento backend.

below error code I get on orders that were placed using the paypal payment pro magento default extension.

There has been an error processing your request The requested Payment Method is not available.

log:

```
#0 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('The requested P...')
#1 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php(119): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
#2 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(50): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getInfoBlock(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#3 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(44): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->setPayment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#4 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_payment', true)
#7 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php(112): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_payment')
#8 /home/../public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info->getPaymentHtml()
#9 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/groovytec...')
#10 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#11 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/../public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#16 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/groovytec...')
#17 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#18 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#23 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#25 /home/../public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#26 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/groovytec...')
#27 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#28 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#29 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#31 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#32 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#33 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(128): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#34 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#35 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#36 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#37 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#38 /home/../public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#39 /home/../public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#40 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try the following (ordered by the effort it would take, if one step does not help you, take the next one)

    Check the allowed countries that you can configure for each payment method in the admin backend.

    Check the error logs (system.log, exception.log after enabling them)

    Debug into the \Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isAvailable() method to see what is going on.
```

also refer:- [Activated but still "The requested Payment Method is not available." as registered user only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/806/activated-but-still-the-requested-payment-method-is-not-available-as-register)

Comment: also check method available by  selecting country and different store views. in configuration.